# Getting current page url from an extension using crossrider

Tags: crossrider

I am trying to set up an extension for firefox, chrome, safari and internet explorer, I am using [crossrider](http://crossrider.com/developers).

Basically I want to display a browser action when clicked displays a popup containing an input text with the current page url and a button that will open a new tab to another url passing the url as a parameter.

Here is what I did based on what I found in the documentation ;

extension.js :

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.request === 'getUrl'){
            appAPI.message.toPopup({url:location.href});
        }
    });
});
```

background.js :

```
var activeTabUrl;

appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('logo-19.jpg');
    appAPI.browserAction.setBadgeText('extn', [255,0,0,125]);
    appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('Add Url to Site');

    appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({resourcePath:'pin.html', height: 300, width: 300});

});
```

pin.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function crossriderMain($) {
            activeTabUrl = null;

            appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
                if (msg.url) {
                    activeTabUrl = msg.url;

                    $('#url').val(activeTabUrl);

                    if(activeTabUrl){
                        $('#addurl').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                }
            });

            appAPI.message.toActiveTab({request:'getUrl'});


            $('#addurl').click(function(){
                var fullUrl = 'http://my.site.com/addurl?url=' + activeTabUrl;
                appAPI.openURL(fullUrl, "tab"); 
            });

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="url" name="url" readonly="true" type="text"/>
        <input id="addurl" type="submit" value="Add Url" disabled/ >

    </body>
</html>
```

Sometimes the field containing the url is not filled, it does not happen on a specific page, for the same page, sometimes it will be displayed, sometimes not. I can't pinpoint a specific cause.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, other than a minor point of declaring **activeTabUrl** in the *pin.html* code and not the *background.js* code as they are different scopes.

From experience, the only thing I can think of that may be causing the issue is that sometimes browsers return the message response before the message listener has initialized. To mitigate this, in the *pin.html* code, add a delay to sending the message requesting the URL, as follows:

```
setTimeout(funtion() {
  appAPI.message.toActiveTab({request:'getUrl'});
}, 0);
```

[**Disclosure**] I am a Crossrider employee